# Windows Phone 8 cellular call to a number without user interaction

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing an application in windows phone 8 which reads the number entered by user and then make cellular call to that number.

Code is -

```
PhoneCallTask callTask = new PhoneCallTask();
callTask.PhoneNumber = number;
callTask.DisplayName = "Adam";
callTask.Show();
```

Problem is - While executing this code, application shows a prompt message "Dial ?" with "Call" and "don't call" buttons and then on clicking on "Call" does the action of originating call. So, looking for a solution which will originate the call without user interaction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, on Windows Phone it isn't possible to make a call without user interaction.

Comment: I wouldn't call that unfortunate, I'd say it was a sensible precaution against malicious apps running up a large phone bill...

Comment: @IanRoberts Agreed. That was more of a "unfortunately for you" :)